Can I use specific preprocess hooks for a node type or a view mode?
Is there a way, on drupal 10/11, to add custom preprocess hook by bundle or view mode in a theme?
An example: the default preprocess to alter node, in theme, is
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {}

Is there a way to create, automatically, hooks for something like mytheme_preprocess_node_VIEW_MODE, or mytheme_preprocess_node_BUNDLE, like the suggestions alter for templates?

Yes, you can do both. But you need two underscores:
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node__BUNDLE(&$variables) {}

function MYTHEME_preprocess_node__BUNDLE__VIEWMODE(&$variables) {}

For example:
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node__page__full(&$variables) {}


And if you need something that isn't built in, you can implement hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK to extend
